# How to construct a branching program for this function?

Tags: algorithms

Suppose we have a formula $F(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1 \vee (x_2 \land x_3)$. $F$ outputs 1 when it has a satisfying assignment and 0 otherwise.

How can I convert the above formula(or any formula like this in general)to a branching program(constant width)?

Comment: Do you know what a branching program is? If so, work out how you would test variables one at a time to evaluate the formula. Each test corresponds to a node in the branching program. There are only 3 variables - you should be able to work it out on paper without much trouble.

Comment: You already got [an answer on CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/41330/5038) that suggested a reference with material about branching programs.  I'm sure there are many other resources as well.  Have you tried reading that book, or another one? It seems to imagine that you've read the entire book and assimilated everything useful in 2 hours.  Perhaps it'd be more effective to spend some time studying standard material first, before asking; that might either help you figure out the answer to your question yourself, or help you identify the source of your confusion more specifically.

Comment: The notion of constant width only makes sense when considering an infinite family of formulas, for example parity of an arbitrary number of inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general way to convert a formula to a branching program. The construction is recursive, and it constructs branching programs with an initial vertex and two terminal vertices, labeled 1 (true) and 0 (false).

- The formula is a variable $x$: the initial vertex queries $x$, and according to the answer proceeds to the two terminal vertices.
- The formula is of the form $\phi \lor \psi$. Construct branching programs $P_\phi,P_\psi$ to the two subformulas. Identify the 0 output of $P_\phi$ with the initial vertex of $P_\psi$, and the 1 outputs of both programs.
- The formula is of the form $\phi \land \psi$. Construct branching programs $P_\phi,P_\psi$ to the two subformulas. Identify the 1 output of $P_\phi$ with the initial vertex of $P_\psi$, and the 0 outputs of both programs.
- The formula is of the form $\lnot \phi$. Construct a branching program for $\phi$, and switch the labels of the terminal vertices.